# How to disable this timer?

Tags: central-heating, timer

Is there a way to completely turn off this timer?

[image: annoying timer]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the 6 tabs (at 6am, 9am, etc.) and it should stop any automated on/off actions.

It's hard to be sure from this vantage, but it appears that 3 of the tabs are light colored, and 3 are darker. The light ones are used to set "on" times, and the dark ones for "off" times.

Comment: It also looks like there's a manual override switch in the top-right. If you want, you can leave in one or more of either the "off" or "on" tabs depending on if you want this to always be on or off -- that way, if someone (accidentally) switches this on, it'll turn off within at most 24 hours (or vice-versa).